# Change wallet creation default directory path

Tags: nodeos, cleos, wallet, keosd, ubuntu

On `ubuntu 18.04`, when I create a new wallet, by default the wallet directory is in the home dir `/home/user/eosio-wallet`. I am storing all eos related data on disk storage whose path is `/storage`. I want the wallet on `/storage`. How to create the wallet on the given path? I tried:

1. Creating a wallet `cleos wallet create --name $walletname --file wallet.txt >&2` , which saves `eosio-wallet` dir on `/home/user`.
2. Move this wallet to storage disk `mv ~/eosio-wallet/ /storage`
3. kill the existing **keosd** using `pkill keosd`
4. Run keosd again with the dir path `keosd --wallet-dir /storage/eosio-wallet/ &`

After this running other commands which try to unlock the wallet. It returns error:

```
"/usr/opt/eosio/2.0.0/bin/keosd" launched
password: Error 3120002: Nonexistent wallet
Are you sure you typed the wallet name correctly?
Error Details:
Unable to open file: /home/user/eosio-wallet/./abc.wallet
```

I am running these commands through shell script. If I separately run `keosd --wallet-dir /storage/eosio-wallet/ &` and then unlock the wallet it works. But I don't want to do this again and again.

My questions are:

1. Can I create a wallet directly into the `/storage` path? If yes then how?
2. Are the above steps correct?
3. Should the **keosd** command need to run again and again whenever I need to access the wallet?
4. Does **keosd** needs the only root dir to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path where wallets are stored in the keosd-config.ini in `~/eosio-wallet/config.ini` permanently. If you do, keosd will always try to find the wallet-files in this directory.

```
# The path of the wallet files (absolute path or relative to application data d$
wallet-dir = "path-to-wallet-files"
```

To use the modified configuration you just have to modify it and restart keosd.

Comment: This means, anyhow I need ```~/eosio-wallet``` in the home directory?

Comment: You just need to store the config.ini-file in ~/eosio-wallet but you could store the wallet-files in a different directory.